# Localhost not found (404) iis

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2012, localhost

I am having several issues with the DNS localhost on my computer.

Some instruction is redirecting all my explorers, including visual studio somewhere else than 127.0.0.1 when I visual studio or any browser looks for localhost.

Where can such thing be happening? I recently changed my hosts file to point localhost somewhere else, but then it did not work so I switched it back, so that cant be the problem.

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost
```

I have also unistalled and installed IIS, so is not a problem of iis not redirecting properly..

I am not being able to run Visual Studio solutions because of this problem.

I have tried pining 127.0.0.1 and it responds, I have also tried localhost and it also works, but when I type localhost on a browser it redirects to a "404" page.

Comment: first try cmd ipconfig /flushdns. I don't think this is the problem but just in case this works it can save you a lot time. If it doesn't help, turn on IIS and check if your website still (exist and) have binding on port 80. Also check if your app pool still (exist and) running.

Comment: I am not able to add applications into the app pool of IIS from visual studio (my ide) because it is not able to find localhost..which should be what iis is listening, will try your option tough

Comment: ipconfig /flushdns did not work..

Comment: I mean check through your IIS Manager, not through Visual studio. Are you using IIS6/7/7.5/8 or IIS express? You can get it through **control panel -> Administrative Tools -> Internet Information Service Manager** if you are not using IIS express

Comment: I am using IIS 8, I have no websites hosted there.

Comment: Well then bad news is you have to recreate the website and its app pool manually on IIS first. This can be very different according to your application and really hard to give a simple intro. A quick way if you just want to run and debug your app. Right click on your website project and click **Use IIS Express**. This will create a temp app on your local IIS express. Not port 80 but at least it runs :)

Comment: Just to correct my wording and avoid misunderstood. **Recreate** I said doesn't means you need to rewrite the code. **Re-register** might be a better word.

Comment: @MaG3Stican: Have you been able to resolve this issue? If so, could you please post your answer. I'm having the same problem and am now stuck :S

Comment: sorry I was unable to find an answer to this problem, I ended up formatting my computer, neither uninstalling IIS or visual studio or anything of the sort did work..

Answer (score 5):

I just had this problem too and it turned out to be an issue with Default Web Site's bindings in IIS. I had specified the "Host Name" to be the server's domain name, meaning external access worked fine but trying to access any IIS page through localhost returned a browser 404 error.

Simply clearing that "Host Name" field and leaving it blank fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I would never have solved this issue without your solution.  I have a customer who was setting up an on-site instance of my software, and they tried to do a bunch of config before we got together to walk through the setup.  They had set the host on both the Default Web Site, as well as the app itself.  But this was breaking it.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that IIS is actually configured to listen on 127.0.0.1 (perhaps you removed the binding previously?)

`netsh http show iplisten

IP addresses present in the IP listen list:
127.0.0.1`

You can add additional IPs like so:

`netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=10.0.0.10`

Answer (score 2):

I added a binding to the site that accepted IP address 127.0.0.1 over port 80 and was able to connect.

Comment: This helped me. I had bindings for my web URLs but did not have one for localhost. Adding a localhost binding worked.